# how to disable UserInteraction for UITableview cell but not in custom button on cell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

How to disable `UserInteraction` for `UITableview` cell but not in custom button on that  cell..

I am creating a button using :

```
    UIButton *dayButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [dayButton setFrame:CGRectMake(201, 0, 30, 35)];
    [dayButton addTarget:self action:@selector(selectDayView) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [dayButton setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"86-camera.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    dayButton.userInteractionEnabled=YES;
    [cell addSubview:dayButton];
```

and then I set

```
    cell.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
```

how can I get `dayButtonAction` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not possible to applies disable `userInteraction` for UITableView and not on `UITableViewCell`. You can access content/controllers of UITableVie (which is sub View of `UITableView`) when `userInteraction` is enable of `UITabelView`. When you add any controller on `UITableView`  actually you added it on `UITableViewCell` but cell is part of `UITableView` so when you disable `userInteraction` on `UITableView` it means it aslo set it(NO) for UITableViewCell.

And Here i aslo give you suggestion for add your `UIButton` to cell as a

```
[cell.contentView addSubView:buttonName];
```

Answer (score 18):

Don't disable user interaction with the whole cell. Set `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone` to prevent the cell selection. That way the user can still interact with the button.

Comment: Thanks this was helpful

Answer (score 3):

If you set the `cell.userinteraction = NO` then you can't touch the button because any interaction is closed for the `cell` and it's `subviews`.

Answer (score 3):

An old question, but think this might help someone. You can disable the user interaction of UITableView by setting the property of selection to no selection.

[image: Identity Inspector]

Answer (score 2):

One more option is to override touchesBegan and touchesEnded. Here's how:

1) make a custom cell with overriding functions and an indicator to apply them or not

```
class MyCustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell { 
    var shouldDisableTouches: Bool = false

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if !shouldDisableTouches { super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event) }
    }

    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        if !shouldDisableTouches { super.touchesEnded(touches, with: event) }
    }
}
```

2) In storyboard set your cell class to this class in Custom Class > Class

3) Now in tableView(_:cellForRowAt:) you are able to turn interactions on or off

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "yourCellIdentifier", for: indexPath) as! MyCustomTableViewCell
    if <your condition here> {
         cell.shouldDisableTouches = true
    } else {
         cell.shouldDisableTouches = false
    }
}
```

...the "else" part is essential here, don't drop it. It is a reusable cell after all.

This kind of disabling don't affect buttons, that are located in a separate xib, registered for this cell. Haven't tested it on a cell, designed directly in the storyboard yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];` also don't implement the `tblView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`. Make you button clickable (as it will be by default). Handle it's event to perform your task.

As of I understand If Superview has `userintercation = no` enabled than it's subview can't be interacted. In your case UITableViewCell is the superview and button is subview. So it is better to avoid setting `cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;` and use `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

If  `cell.userinteraction = NO` then you can't touch  it's `subviews`. Simple way is Just take on `UIView` with `clearColour` and size of the view is same as your Cell size and put it on the cell and above view you can set your `UIButton`. when you want to `cell.userinteraction = NO` then just set `view.hidden=NO` and when `cell.userinteraction = Yes` then set `view.hidden=YES`. so your Transparent `UIView` display and above view your `UIButton` then you can get the Click of button. no need to set `cell.userinteraction`.

Answer (score 0):

You can't set User Interaction Disabled on Cell because it's a Super View on which button is added.if you do,you will not able to interact with button so disable the interaction on rest of sub-views of UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

[Swift]
What worked for me is,
cell.isUserInteractionEnabled = true (I mean not to set it as false, default is true)

and set,

cell.selectionStyle = .none