# Disable UITableViewCell, but leave detail button accessory enabled

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

I'm trying to have it so that any interaction with a `UITableViewCell` is ignored, **but** still allow a user to click on the accessory (the detail button), which will show an alert explaining why the cell cannot be clicked on.

`isUserInteractionEnabled` seems to be an all or nothing situation. Is there any way to keep the detail button enabled?

Comment: Do you want to apply that behavior to specific cells or to all the cells in your tableView? Also, do you want to be able to switch back and forth between enabling and disabling cell interaction or you just want that to be the default behavior?

Comment: The behavior will be for specific cells that meet certain conditions. I don't understand the second question. If X is true, disable the cell except for the indicator. The workaround I came up with so far is to leave `isUserInteractionEnabled` true, set `selectionStyle` to none, and in the `didSelectRowAt` function, make a quick check at the top testing the same condition, and if it's true, just return.

Answer (score 1):

Don't disable user interaction with the whole cell. Set cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone to prevent the cell selection. That way the user can still interact with the button.

Please check this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/a/17523023/2991942